# How can I redirect standard output to a program in CMD?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, command-prompt

I am running this in the command prompt:

```
python -c ""print("""Message from python""")"" | AcceptMessage.exe
```

However, this does not work. I get the message:

```
close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
```

`AcceptMessage.exe` takes in one argument. All it does is just print out what was passed to it. Meaning, if you normally call it via `AcceptArgument.exe argument_here`, the output would be `argument_here`. I've tested the actual program, and it works fine normally, so that's not the problem.

I'm pretty new to scripting in general, so I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: looks like accept exe does not read the input stream. You'll have to capture the python output with for /f and pass it as an argument to accept exe

Comment: So something like `for /f %q in (python -c ""print("""Message""")"") do AcceptMessage.exe %q`? I just get `"") was unexpected at this time.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this (save the script with .bat extension)

```
0<0# : ^
''' 
@echo off

for /f "tokens=* delims="  %%a in ('python "%~f0" %*') do (
    AcceptMessage "%%a"
)
exit /b 0
'''

print("message from python")
```

or like that:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('"python -c ""print("""Message from python""")"""') do (
    acceptMessage "%%a"
)
```

if you want to run it directly from the command line:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %a in ('"python -c ""print("""Message from python""")"""') do @AcceptMessage "%a"
```